# How can i check if the file contains the args[0] parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell

So the task is to check if the time given in args[0] ( for example 20:30 )
is in the text document that looks like this.
(ABC-123, 20:00
 BCA-321, 15:20
 CBA-231, 21:30
 etc etc.)

i've tried doing it with this code

```
$foglalas = Get-Content C:\users\Ádám\desktop\teligumi.txt

if ($foglalas -contains $args[0])
{
  Write-Host "Foglalt időpont"
}
else {Write-Host "Jó időpont!"}
```

But it always says it doesn't contain it no matter if it actually does, or not.
Yes, i know its a beginner question but i'm really stuck with it, any solution would be welcome.

Comment: `contains` is for checking if an array containts EXACTLY this element, you need `-like "*$args[0]*"`

Comment: Or `-match [regex]::escape($args[0])`

Comment: @4c74356b41 that indexing inside a string interpolation won't work, it would need to be "*$($args[0])*"

Comment: ah, right, forgot about it

Comment: thanks a lot guys, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also another approach:

```
$foglalas = Get-Content C:\users\Ádám\desktop\teligumi.txt | Where {$_ -match [regex]::Escape($args[0])}

if ($foglalas) { Write-Host "Foglalt időpont" } 
else {Write-Host "Jó időpont!"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use select-string with -quiet option which return boolean and -simplematch for not evaluate regex

```
if ($args[0] -and (Select-String -Path "C:\users\Ádám\desktop\teligumi.txt" -Pattern $args[0] -Quiet -SimpleMatch))
{
 Write-Host "Foglalt időpont"
}
else 
{
Write-Host "Jó időpont!"
}
```